# Source code for adding new GNU assembler x86 instruction and recompile

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am trying to figure out which file I need to modify in binutils project so I can add a new x86 instruction `mov2` which will be exact copy of `mov`. Searching source folder resulted hundred of result yet still I couldnt find any file containing instruction references.

Thank you

Comment: If you literally just want to be able to say `mov2` where you can say `mov` now, perhaps a pre-processing app would work.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError after I figure out I want to add also custom logic into mov2

Comment: [opcodes/i386-opc.tbl](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/i386-opc.tbl;h=1c1a69a897ba0666556ef4bce3478bdbbe1c5676;hb=HEAD)

Comment: thanks Jester! Would you mind to add as an answer, so I would choose?

Comment: Maybe you can instead add a self answer detailing all the steps needed to add the instruction. That would likely be more useful to other people.

Comment: @Jester sure I can do, if nothing goes wrong, finishing an LFS I will do on weekend unless some hero willing to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @[Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) mentioned file needs to be modified is [opcodes/i386-opc.tbl](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/i386-opc.tbl;h=1c1a69a897ba0666556ef4bce3478bdbbe1c5676;hb=HEAD) also I had to bother him on IRC for further details but he was kind enough to guide me. I might note that I was only able to generate on binutils v2.25, I believe later branches start using different solution, might be related with "make run-cgen" target but its study for another day:)

Here are the steps I have followed:

Create temp dirs, one for build and one for binaries:

```
$mkdir -pv /tmp/{instruction-test,tools}
$cd /tmp/instruction-test/
```

clone the binutils repo or you can download straight from gnu ftp:

```
$git clone http://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

switch to branch:

```
$cd binutils/
$git checkout binutils-2_25
```

pre-build project:

```
$mkdir -v build
$cd build
$../configure --prefix=/tmp/tools  --with-sysroot=/tmp/tools  --with-lib-path=/tmp/tools/lib  --target=x86_64-custom-linux-gnu  --disable-nls  --disable-werror

$make clean
$time make -s -j XX > make.log || { echo "can not make project, please check logs installation aborted" ; exit 1; }
```

now add mov2 instructions as exact copy of mov

```
$cd ../opcodes
$cat i386-opc.tbl | egrep -e '^mov,' | sed 's/mov/mov2/g' >> i386-opc.tbl
```

now you can pause here and look what we have added:

```
$git diff i386-opc.tbl
```

now we need to update i386 opcode table as well:

```
$cd ../build/opcodes
$make i386-gen
$./i386-gen --srcdir=$(pwd)/../../opcodes
```

now we can rebuild and install into /tmp/tools:

```
$cd ..
$time make -s > make.log
$make -s install > install.log
```

time to test! Here is small example with new instructions:

```
$cat > /tmp/hello << EOF
        .global _start

        .text
_start:
        # write(1, message, 13)
        mov2     $1, %rax                # system call 1 is write
        mov2     $1, %rdi                # file handle 1 is stdout
        mov2     $message, %rsi          # address of string to output
        mov2     $13, %rdx               # number of bytes
        syscall                         # invoke operating system to do the write

        # exit(0)
        mov2     $60, %rax               # system call 60 is exit
        xor     %rdi, %rdi              # we want return code 0
        syscall                         # invoke operating system to exit
message:
        .ascii  "Hello, world\n"
EOF
$cd /tmp/tools/bin
$./x86_64-custom-linux-gnu-as -o /tmp/hello.o /tmp/hello
$ld /tmp/hello.o -o /tmp/hello.bin
$cd /tmp/
$./hello.bin
```

now you should be able to see output:

```
Hello, world
```

If you hit issues I suspect it would be related with cat/EOF command, you can simply try with your own file. As I mentioned this is not up to date solution and I had trouble running i386-gen on later branches which I believe managed by cgen? or maybe I needed to deal with stdin used [here](https://github.com/qunixorg/binutils/blob/qunix-v0.0.1/opcodes/i386-gen.c#L1386)  but I didnt have much time